# twurl followers/ids.json ALWAYS returns my own followers

Tags: json, twitter

Here is my twurl command:

```
twurl "cursor=-1&screen_name=FOREXcom&count=5000" /1.1/followers/ids.json
```

This twitter account has 70K followers. When I do the above command I get my own 1600+ followers in the list.

The command is formulated according to Twitter API guidelines here:
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids

I have tried with and without a cursor, using either screen_name or user_id or both. I have also passed `count=1000`. Nothing works. I always get all 1600+ of my own followers. It's as though I were not passing any arguments at all.

Can anyone see any errors in my command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format I used is for POST requests, with the -d switch added, of course.

GET requests should have the parameters appended as in a query string:

```
twurl "/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=FOREXcom&count=5000"
```

The above query works.